# A good translation for 'do x to win'

Tags: перевод

I'm having a hard time finding a good translation for some simple calls to action on a website that are all variants of:

> do x to win

The `do x` can be one of a few different verbs but the `to win` bit has me stumped. Someone has suggested I use `и побеждайте` but that doesn't sound right.

Examples of phrases are "Guess the sound to win" or "Listen carefully to win"

Comment: Сделайте X, чтобы победить

Comment: It's in development so I can't give you a link unfortunately. Examples of phrases are `Guess the sound to win` or `Listen carefully to win`

Comment: You need reverse order in this phrase: > Чтобы победить, нажмите Х. In this way it sounds better for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Нажмите кнопку и выиграйте!" is the most closest one. 
First of all, it assumes that second action (win something) is imposed by a first action (do something). Second, it sound motivating. Third, it is shorter than "чтобы победить, сделай то-то" form.

I'm much obliged to @YellowSky for pointing out that "выиграйте" is better than "победите".

Comment: "Победить" implies competition with others, there's another verb, "выиграть", like "to win a prize" - "выиграть приз".

Comment: @YellowSky, very good point, don't thought about the fact that this is about выиграть. You know what, I'll make this a comment.

Comment: http://leto.bystrobank.ru/